# Merge dictionary with dataframe on common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

```
{
    ('x', 1): 1, 
    ('y', 2): 2, 
    ('z', 3): 3
}
```

I also have the following dataframe:

```
index   data    common
 0      ('x',1)
 1      ('y',2)
 2      ('z',3)
```

I would like to merge the dictionary with the dataframe. I want to compare the Key value in the dictionary to the data value in the dataframe and if they are the same, set the dictionary Value to the df.common value. The resulting dictionary would be:

```
index   data      common
 0      ('y',2)      2
 1      ('x',1)      1
 2      ('z',3)      3
```

I have tried the following:

```
m = pd.Series(dictionary)
df['common']= m
```

I have tried to use map, but that doesn't allow you to reindex multiindexed values.

Comment: can you post your dictionary in a normal dictionary format because I don't know if your keys are tuples or that is just a typo

Comment: map works with the dictionary, just try `df['common'] = df.data.map(dictionary)`

Answer (score 1):

One way which @DanielMesejo commented is:

```
df.assign(common=df.data.map(d))

     data  common
0  (x, 1)       1
1  (y, 2)       2
2  (z, 3)       3
```

Another way is like this:

```
from operator import getitem
from functools import partial

p = partial(getitem, d)

df.assign(common=df.data.apply(p))

     data  common
0  (x, 1)       1
1  (y, 2)       2
2  (z, 3)       3
```

Where `d` is your dictionary